# Alternate of ActiveXObject in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am writing some javascript code for one of the legacy which is supposed to run on Internet Explorer version. For the same, i am using  **ActiveXObject** like

```
  var sbr = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

It is working well but I am getting a prompt screen like **"An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction ?"**

How to remove this prompt without changing IE settings?. Is there any any alternate of the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove that prompt. It is a security feature and is controlled by the individual user's security settings.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.